# Check for app Installed or not in iOS WITHOUT ALERT in safari

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

I want to check in iOS safari that one of my app is installed or not. I have implemented URL schemes for the app and I have revoked app if its installed.

Now I want to show my custom alert in iOS safari if my app is not installed. I have implemented below JS but it shows iOS default alert which I don't need.

```
setTimeout(function() 
{
  window.location = "http://www.google.com";                           
}, 1);
window.location = "custom-uri://AppShouldListenForThis";
```

Is there any way to check it without any native alert from iOS safari.

I have also tried to implement try catch for it but exception was handled by os itself. Not catch statement executed.